# Is there any alternative method for Bulk uploading data from excel rather than using windows service with .net?

Tags: javascript, c#, ssis, windows-services, worker-service

Currently we are using windows service with C# code for bulk uploading Excel files, As the c# code reads each row in the excel file and inserts that row in SQL db it takes time to insert when the rows are more. And if there are many files to be served windows service picks only 1 file at a time. How can I improve the performance of bulk uploading. Is there any Other approach to do the Bulk upload from excel file without using windows service?

I searched for this solution but failed to get the exact solution, whether is it possible to achieve this through SSIS?

Note: I have few validations of data too to insert a record in SQL db.